# Retrieve traditional html form data in Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

Creating a form dynamically and calling submit on form as shown below:

```
const mapForm = document.createElement('form');
mapForm.setAttribute('id', 'export-file');
// mapForm.setAttribute('content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); - is it needed?
mapForm.target = '_blank';
mapForm.method = 'POST';
mapForm.action = '/export';
mapForm.acceptCharset = 'UTF-8';

const postData = {
  fileType: exportType,
  data: someJsonArray
}

let formData = [
  {
    name: 'postData',
    value: JSON.stringify(postData)
  }
]

formData.forEach(input => {
  const element = document.createElement('input');
  element.type = 'hidden';
  element.name = input.name;
  element.value = input.value;
  mapForm.appendChild(element);
});

document.body.appendChild(mapForm);
mapForm.submit();
```

On Node server I have these:

```
app.use('/export', bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use('/export', exportAPI);
```

and exportAPI.js file has the following:

don't see any data when I log req.body.

```
router.post('/',(req, res)  => {
    try {
        logger.info(req.body); -- DONT SEE ANY DATA IN THIS LINE
        //....
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error('error in export');
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: What does the network tab says ?

Comment: network tab has no errors or anything

Comment: I mean to ask, what data does it transfer ?

Comment: element.name = input.name; - 'postData'
element.value = input.value; - 'Stringified json objecvt'

Comment: If the network tab carries actual data, then server should receive it

Answer (score 0):

The form action is pointing to '/export' but your node middleware its on '/datacloud/orgbm/export'. So it basically node is not getting the right request.

Can you change the form action to '/datacloud/orgbm/export'?

Comment: Do you see any logger on `router.post('/',(req, res)  => {` ?

Comment: I see headers and all other stuff in the request except the valeu I passed in form